# Java cache synchronise with database

Tags: java, database, caching, jersey

I have a java web application and I want to store the data coming through a jersey rest service. This rest call is very frequent, so I cannot store the data in database directly for every call. So I am thinking to use an in memory cache to store the data for few rest calls and synchronise with db periodically. How should I do this? Should I schedule some runnable that will poll the db periodically to update it? Is there any better method?

Comment: How frequent? Could you put the messages in a queue and have a background thread save them?

Comment: @Kayaman I think that is possible. Thank you very much.